# Insert number 1-2 but not 2-1

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have (1,2,3) and i want insert in my table:

```
1-2
2-3
```

But I want exclude `2-1` and `3-2`.

Any help?

Comment: Why do you want to insert 1-2 and 2-3? Is it because they are adjacent? What if the list was (1,2,4,5,8) - what would you want to insert then?

Comment: tank's Dimitri.. very nice.. br Max

Answer (score 1):

First get the cartesian product of the items. Then exclude those with difference more than 1 and first number >= second number. Like this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(){1, 2, 3};

var result = from n1 in list
             from n2 in list
             select new {n1, n2};

result = result.Where(n=> (n.n1 < n.n2) && (n.n2 - n.n1 == 1)).ToList();
```

This will give you what you want:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyrz7.jpg)

Comment: This is a possibly correct and possibly incorrect answer to a very underspecified question. It assumes (1, 2, 4) should only result in a (1, 2) record, but it's very well possible that (2, 4) is also wanted.

Comment: @hvd Yes the question is under specified, but he determined that they are three numbers `1,2,3` and the results should be only `1,2`, and `2,3`. And this what the code gives, I am waiting for the op to add more info.

Comment: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ#lead may be a way of doing this with better O notation performance (basically look at pairs of entries, rather than **every** combination).